# Flutter dropdown value if not selected, then assign the initial value

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I have a `DropDownButtonFormField` I need to check this. If the dropdown value is not selected by the user then assign the initial value when submitting.

### Custom DropDown

```
 Container myDropDownContainer(String initialVal, List<String> listItems,
      String text, Function myFunc, Function validate) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 120,
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: kTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
              child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                //menuMaxHeight: 300,
                validator: (value) {
                  if(value!.isEmpty) {
                    return "485s4a8sd4as85";
                  }
                } ,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                isExpanded: true,
                onTap: () => myFunc,
                //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                value: initialVal,
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_downward,
                  color: Colors.black38,
                ),
                iconSize: 24,
                elevation: 16,
                dropdownColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                style: kTextStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                onChanged: (val) => myFunc(val),
                items: listItems.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String? val) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    //TODO: Set default values
                    value: val,
                    child: Text(
                      val,
                      style: kTextStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is my `onChanged` property that assigns the selected value by the user. I added some explanations about what I am trying to do.

```
 String _valueCinsiyet = "Diğer"; // initial value
  void onChangedCinsiyet(String? newVal) {
    setState(() {
      if(newVal==null) {
        _formData.setCinsiyet(_valueCinsiyet);
        /*
        'if newVal is null' means that if the value is not selected by the user
        then set the initialValue( _valueCinsiyet)
         */

      } else {
        /*
        if newVal is not null then assign the newVal( which means the selected value)
        into my initialValue, then set the data to use it on different pages. What is missing?
         */
        _valueCinsiyet = newVal;
        _formData.setCinsiyet(_valueCinsiyet);
      }

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nullable data to track `DropdownButtonFormField` changes. Being nullable you can check if it is null or not, no need to anything extra on `onChanged:` just assign new value usual way.

On state before build method:  `String? value; // value to keep track`

```dart
child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
  value: value,
  onChanged: (val) {
    setState(() {
      value = val;
    });
  },
```

Now `onSaved`/submit button you can pass value by checking null, simple way is

`value?? "default Value"`. In your case, it is `value??Diğer`

Comment: If I specify the initialValue as above, initialValue will be null. Can you show the exact changes in my code?

Comment: You can also set initial value, in that case you won't get null from dropdown, Can you include `listItems` and on your `TODO:` `value: val ?? "default value"`